# Problem with \bordermatrix inside array

Tags: matrices, arrays

When a `\bordermatrix` is placed inside an `array`, the spacing between rows will be wrong (see the MWE below). What is causing this problem? Is there a solution?

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

A simple matrix created with \verb+\bordermatrix+; right spacing between rows:
\[
  \bordermatrix{%
    & 1 & 2 \cr
    1 & x1 & x2 \cr
    2 & x3 & x4 \cr
    3 & x5 & x6}
\]

The same matrix inside an \texttt{array}; wrong spacing between rows:
\[
\begin{array}{c}
  \bordermatrix{%
    & 1 & 2 \cr
    1 & x1 & x2 \cr
    2 & x3 & x4 \cr
    3 & x5 & x6}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused because the `\bordermatrix` uses the `\baselineskip` for the spacing and `array` sets this to 0pt.

Restoring the value of `\baselineskip` in the cell fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\[
\edef\savedbaselineskip{\the\baselineskip\relax}
\begin{array}{c}
    {\baselineskip=\savedbaselineskip
    \bordermatrix{%
    & 1 & 2 \cr
    1 & x1 & x2 \cr
    2 & x3 & x4 \cr
    3 & x5 & x6}}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

This is done inside a group to keep the definition local.

Answer (score 2):

An altenative way to restoring `\baselineskip`, which has been shown by Martin, is using `\parbox` or `minipage` for embedding the `\bordermatrix`, within the array. This would also restore the spacing.